# Integral mean value theorem on the sphere.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, spheres

Let $\mathbb{S}^d$ be an unit sphere with dimension $d$.

Do we have an integral mean value theorem on the unit sphere? That is we can find
a point $t\in\mathbb{S}^d$, such that $$f(t)=\frac{\int_{\mathbb{S}^d}f(y)d\sigma(y)}{\int_{\mathbb{S}^d} d\sigma(y)}?$$

Since we have this result on the interval case: on the interval $[a,b]$, we can find a point $t\in(a,b)$, s.t. $$\int_a^bf(x)dx=f(t)(b-a).$$ Not quite sure this also works on the sphere.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: How does a function $f(t)$ "represent" a point??  Show how it works in $\mathbb{R}$ first.

Comment: Sorry I mean the function value of a point. I will correct it.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand the whole point of this question.  If you want to write a function of a point, $f(t)$, well... what is wrong with just $f(t)$?

Comment: There is no $t$ on the right hand side. So, no. And what is $\sigma$?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion on my question. Since on the interval [a,b] in R, we have a point t in [a,b] s.t. $f(t)=\frac{\int_a^bf(x)dx}{\int_a^b dx}$, I was just wondering if this is also works on the sphere. The similar identity is my question written in the above. $d \sigma$ is the surface Lebesgue measure on the sphere. Sorry for the confusion, guys!

Comment: Makes absolutely no sense to write a function of $t$ that has no $t$ on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is a continuous function $S^d\to \mathbb R$, then the answer is yes, for the same reason as the usual integral mean value theorem (essentially the intermediate value theorem). Namely, the value on the right of your equation is some real number between the maximum and minimum value of $f$. Since $f$ is continuous and $S^d$ is connected (assuming $d>0$), the image of $f$ is an interval and hence contains all numbers between its maximum and minimum.

If $f$ maps to a higher-dimensional space, the answer may be no, for example the inclusion $f: S^1 \to \mathbb R^2$ has average value $0\in \mathbb R^2$ but does not attain that value.

If $f$ is not continuous, then certainly the answer is no in general.